# How to create and hide user login link in drupal 7?

Tags: users

Hello everyone I am new to drupal, I want to know the steps to create user-login link in menu bar and after user-login this link should be convert into logout link. Can any one help me ?

Comment: Just add 2 links to the menu, one for user/login and one for user/logout. The permission system will take care of hiding them for you

Answer (score 0):

Goto

```
Admin -> Structure -> Block -> User login [Region : None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two links to needed menu manually. First - user/login, second - user/logout, the system control link permissions, so when you are not logged, you can see login link and vice versa, when you logged in - you can see logout link and cannot see login link.